# PHP uploads only one file when I need many

Tags: php, for-loop, file-upload, foreach, upload

I need to run this code applying to each file uploaded:

```
$uploads_dir = 'tdump';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['upfiles']["tmp_name"];
    $name = basename($_FILES['upfiles']["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    $filename="$uploads_dir/$name";
    echo "$filename";
    $mp3file=new CMP3File;
    $mp3file->getid3($filename);
    echo "Title: $mp3file->title<br>\n";
    echo "Artist: $mp3file->artist<br>\n";
    echo "Album: $mp3file->album<br>\n";
    echo "Year: $mp3file->year<br>\n";
    echo "Comment: $mp3file->comment<br>\n";
    echo "Genre: " . Ord($mp3file->genre) . "<br>\n";
```

I tried this so far:

```
$total = count($_FILES['upfiles']['name']);
print_r($total);
for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++){
    $uploads_dir = 'tdump';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['upfiles']["tmp_name"];
    $name = basename($_FILES['upfiles']["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    $filename="$uploads_dir/$name";
    echo "$filename";
    $mp3file=new CMP3File;
    $mp3file->getid3($filename);
    echo "Title: $mp3file->title<br>\n";
    echo "Artist: $mp3file->artist<br>\n";
    echo "Album: $mp3file->album<br>\n";
    echo "Year: $mp3file->year<br>\n";
    echo "Comment: $mp3file->comment<br>\n";
    echo "Genre: " . Ord($mp3file->genre) . "<br>\n";
}
```

html code:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="upfiles[]" type="file" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

mp3file variable is getid3 library, don't focus on it. The thing I can't figure out in this whole bunch of code is how to loop through each uploaded file, get its name and save it. I think it should be for or foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i<your_no_of_files; $i++)
{
    $tmp_name = $file["tmp_name"];
$name = basename($file["name"]).$i;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
$filename="$uploads_dir/$name";
echo "$filename";
$mp3file=new CMP3File;
$mp3file->getid3($filename);
echo "Title: $mp3file->title<br>\n";
echo "Artist: $mp3file->artist<br>\n";
echo "Album: $mp3file->album<br>\n";
echo "Year: $mp3file->year<br>\n";
echo "Comment: $mp3file->comment<br>\n";
echo "Genre: " . Ord($mp3file->genre) . "<br>\n";
}**MAYBE THIS WILL WORK**
```

Comment: that looks nice, but how do I count my number of files?

Answer (score 0):

HTML example :

```
    <input type="file" name="filename[]">
    <input type="file" name="filename[]">
    ....
    <input type="file" name="filename[]">
```

Try do like that, instead of "filename" use your.

PHP example :

```
  if ($_FILES){
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['filename']['name']); $i++) {

            //......
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']["tmp_name"][$i];
            //......

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your form part edit the following attribute

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" />
```

this userfile array will store all your file in an array.

then use `count()` function to display the no of elements.

for e.g.

```
$no_of_files=count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: I uploaded my html, here's what I get:

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: upfiles in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReactSynchro\itunes.php on line 4

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReactSynchro\itunes.php on line 4
0

Comment: check using if(isset($_FILES['userfile or whatever you write']['tmp_name']){ echo 'hi';}

Comment: if it says hi then try again using previous code with improved syntax